# How to join www to non-www rewrite rule with the existing

Tags: regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I am trying to add www to non-www rewrite to the existing:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

I have tried:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

#Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ http://%1/$1 [R=301,L]

RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

How can I join these two rewrite rules?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use:

```
RewriteEngine On

#Redirect www to non-www
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\.(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ http://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^(.+)$ index.php?url=$1 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: I can see why you moved it above -d -f -l. Can you please explain the difference between /$1 and {REQUEST_URI} and also why you added NE. If it is too much too explain, please point me to some good read if you know any.

Comment: You can check [Apache Manual](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/intro.html) `NE` is for `noescape` and `/$1` is pretty much same as `%{REQUEST_URI}` but if .htaccess is in sub directory then they represent different values.